# Cannot make sense of keras.datasets.imdb

Tags: tensorflow, keras, dataset, tensorflow-datasets, imdb

I have two problems:

1. First off, the documentation for `tf.keras.datasets.imdb.get_word_index` says

> Retrieves the dictionary mapping word indices back to words.

While in fact it's the contrary,

`print(tf.keras.datasets.imdb.get_word_index())`

> {'fawn': 34701, 'tsukino': 52006, 'nunnery': 52007

2. I tried to run this in TensorFlow 2.0

```py
(train_data_raw, train_labels), (test_data_raw, test_labels) = keras.datasets.imdb.load_data()
words2idx = tf.keras.datasets.imdb.get_word_index()
idx2words = {idx:word for word, idx in words2idx.items()}
i = 0
train_ex = [idx2words[x] for x in train_data_raw[0]]
train_ex = ' '.join(train_ex)
print(train_ex)
```

This result in a nonsense string

> the as you with out themselves powerful lets loves their [...]

Shouldn't I get a valid movie review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a bit of digging and found that there are a few "offsets" in the processing which need to be undone in order to return a sensible review language.  I modified your line to subtract 3 from the index that appears in the raw sequence (since the default is to start real words with index=3), and also the first character is a dummy marker (set to 1), so the real text starts at position 2 (or index 1 in python).

```
train_ex = [idx2words[x-3] for x in train_data_raw[0][1:]]
```

Using the above modification gives me the following for the review you originally selected:

```
this film was just brilliant casting location scenery story direction everyone's really suited the part they played ...
```

It appears that some punctuation and capitalization is removed etc, but this seems to return sensible reviews.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, where did you find the proper documentation for the correct offset?